# Size limit for nvarchar(max) , Print issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, nvarchar

I want to save  XML record that length is more than 43679 char and its saved into table.
Because when i'm checking its length its giving more than 43679 char but when i'm going to read or Print data of this column its only showing 43679 char.

The below image can help you to understand the problem.

[image]

like example

```
declare @t table (a nvarchar(max));
insert into @t (a) values (REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),'a'),200000));
select LEN(a) from @t  -- result 200000
select print(a) from @t -- print only 43679 char.
```

Please help me out of this situation.

Comment: Nvarchar(max) can store upto 2 GB.Could you please provide more info on what you are trying to do with examples and tag RDBMS

Comment: As an aside, why are you storing your XML as an `nvarchar(max)` rather than the `xml` data type? Please try to create a [mcve] for this - at least a minimal table definition, and some dummy data to populate it, to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I just updated my question. nvarchar(max) saved more than 43679 char, But when I'm getting this value (print). it's only print 43679 char.

Comment: Beside the fact, that XML should live in XML column rather than in a string type, you should - if this is just an issue in output - check the max length for text within your query's options (right click)

Comment: Okay. Here's *my* sample that can fit in a comment: `declare @t table (a nvarchar(max));insert into @t (a) values (REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),'a'),200000));select LEN(a) from @t`. It prints 200000. So, your turn. Please edit your question with a sample that *demonstrates* your issue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever below your query write 'select a from t'
and print 'a' value it only showing 43679  char not 200000.

Comment: @ArvindAgrahari - Neither of which are present in the queries that we're having to re-type from your *image* file rather than being able to copy *code*. And any limitations there are related to how *management studio* displays data, not to a fundamental limit in how SQL Server *stores* data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry for that.
I have updated the question and mention one example there.

Comment: What is Version of your SQL Server..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [well known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499608/ssms-can-not-paste-more-than-43679-characters-from-a-column-in-grid-mode) in SSMS, You can't paste more than 43679 char from a grid view column and unfortunately this limit can't be increased, You can get around this by displaying your Data in Xml format instead of nvarchar

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio has a character limit when printing to the messages pane. There is a workaround to achieve what you need.

Using FOR XML to select your data using TYPE you can specify [processing-instruction] and give it a name. Your text will be presented as a link which you can open. This text will have  wrappers and the name you specified. Here is an example.

```
declare @t table (a nvarchar(max));
insert into @t (a) values (REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),'a'),200000));
select LEN(a) from @t  -- result 200000
SELECT a [processing-instruction(TextOutput)] from @t FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The datatypes like NCHAR, NVARCHAR, NVARCHAR(MAX) stores half of CHAR, VARCHAR & NVARCHAR(MAX). Because these datatype used to store UNICODE characters. Use these datatypes when you need to store data other then default language (Collation). UNICODE characters take 2 bytes for each character. That's why lenth of NCHAR, NVARCHAR, NVARCHAR(MAX) stores half of CHAR, VARCHAR & NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: he is not exceeding default limit  in this case